# Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac Version 17.0 (build 8989) have issue (iOS app not running)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2022 for Mac and Xcode version 13.4. When I'm trying to run any application in iOS Simulator it shows this error:

> #### error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'com.companyname.ProCalendar' on the device 'iOS 15.5 (19F70) - iPhone 11': Application launch for 'com.companyname.ProBus' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.

There must be some issue with this IDE because the same projects are working fine in Visual Studio 2019. Does anyone know the workaround?

#### Visual Studio 2022 for Mac details

```
Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac
Version 17.0 (build 8989)
Installation UUID: 195d8d45-8498-4720-8d1b-e8cc1ce9085f

Runtime
.NET 6.0.3 (64-bit)
Architecture: Arm64

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.1.0-3.22075.3+592501cbb9c9394072a245c15b3458ff88155d85

NuGet
Version: 6.0.0.262

.NET SDK (Arm64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Sdks
SDK Version: 6.0.300
MSBuild SDKs: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Sdks

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK Versions:
    6.0.300
    6.0.101
    5.0.408
    5.0.404
    3.1.419
    3.1.416

.NET Runtime (Arm64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Version: 6.0.5

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    6.0.5
    6.0.1
    5.0.17
    5.0.13
    3.1.25
    3.1.22

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.8.0.19
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 13.4 (20503)
Build 13F17a

Xamarin.Mac
Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 15.10.0.1 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 568bdb24e
Branch: d17-2
Build date: 2022-04-08 18:52:57-0400

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.1.5.90
Hash: 53f47efde
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-0-vsmac
Build date: 2022-05-18 17:28:05 UTC

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 5.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 31.0.3
SDK Build Tools Version: 30.0.3

Build Information: 
Mono: adf1bc4
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-2@9760f0a9
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/v7.0.1@912d149
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.38.2@7b1e016
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d17-2@fc3c2ac


Build Information
Release ID: 1700008989
Git revision: 55998773faa2cb1dda7aab5fecd1625f7b664d10
Build date: 2022-05-18 17:25:46+00
Build branch: release-17.0
Build lane: release-17.0

Operating System
Mac OS X 12.4.0
Darwin 21.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0
    Tue Apr 26 21:08:29 PDT 2022
    root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
```

Comment: If you create a new app project, does that build and run ok?

Comment: No that also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/14834), please try install this package: [xamarin.ios-15.10.0.5.pkg](https://bosstoragemirror.blob.core.windows.net/wrench/d17-2/96b3edb6de5d93b1ff839c71cdb87eb39a15d64c/6169905/package/notarized/xamarin.ios-15.10.0.5.pkg).

If you need to revert to the released stable version, you can just select the stable channel in VSMac and update Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: I have tried this and it's working. Thanks!